# How can I redirect the output of a command (running in a batch loop) to a file?

Tags: redirect, batch-file, xmllint

I have a windows batch file, which iterates over files in a folder and runs a command on each file. Specifically I am running xmllint to validate some files:

```
for %%i in (c:\temp\*.xml) do (
   C:\XMLLINT\xmllint -noout -schema "C:\schemas\schema.xsd" "%%~dpnxi" >> c:\output.txt
)
```

It currently shows the output on screen. I want to show the output of all these commands placed in an output file. How can I achieve this? By using the append operator (>>) nothing is accomplished except for a blank file being created.

Is it because of xmllint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to redirect error output from the program, it might be writing to stderr.  You can try to redirect it with:

```
for %%i in (c:\temp\*.xml) do (
   C:\XMLLINT\xmllint -noout -schema "C:\schemas\schema.xsd" "%%~dpnxi" >> c:\output.txt 2>&1
)
```

Basically the `2>&1` at the end means redirect anything from `stderr` (which is 2) to `stdout` (which is 1).  Since `stdout` is redirected to a file, you should now see the `stderr` stream in the file.  Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but if its documentation is [here](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html), have you tried just removing your "-noout" option, or adding an: "-output c:\output.txt"?

Comment: -noout is to not output the contents of the file being validated, adding -output would not result in one file with all the output in it.